# WpfRibbonApplication - Does not let me add stuff to the ribbon!

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controls, ribbon

Ok so when I go to create a new project in Visual C# 2010 Express i have several options, to create a normal WPF App or to create a WPF RIBBON App.

As you can see below, every time I want to add SOMETHING to the ribbon, it's disabled. Why? What use is a ribbon that won't let you add stuff? How can I get this beast to let me add stuff to my ribbon?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's Ribbon is still a preview and therefore does not have full designer support. The Items collection is of type UIElementCollection, which is fairly general.

So control developers need to tell Visual Studio what the valid types that can be added to Items using [NewItemTypesAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.propertyediting.newitemtypesattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). But since the design experience for the Ribbon is currently missing, the dialog above cannot add items.

Comment: Ahhh, okay. Thanks heaps for clearing that up for me. I've since discovered a nice little Windows Forms ribbon over at CodeProject.com which works great.